# Наследование значений свойств в css (sass)

Tags: css, css3, sass

Вот типичная ситуация с абсолютно позиционированным элементом:
[image: 123]
То есть логика css такова, что при ховере свойство `transform` просто заменяется тем, что описано при ховере. Ну логично, но проблема остается. Если для абсолютного поз. элемента такого рода операцию не делать, то, как в данном примере, этот элемент просто вернется `translate`-ом на свое место (как будто применится `translate(0)`). 
Может, я чего-то не знаю про свойства в css? Или как работать с sass? Возможно. Поэтому интересует, как унаследовать значение свойства родителя, которое уже по цепочке вложенности задано?

Comment: Может `inherit` ?

Comment: @Yuri, это первое что я попробовал и сразу же ощутил себя тупым :D

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется что определенная логика тут есть - краткая запись сбрасывает все свойства, которые не указаны явно:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
div:hover {
  background: center center;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Это полная сбрасывает, а краткая - нет. [Пример](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/vgXgpQ). Поменяй местами их.

Comment: Ну и я осведомлен об этом, тем не менее, я не знаю как решить ситуацию с `transform`, ведь свойства через пробел задаются-то и все равноправны. То есть это не `background-color` или `background-position`. Нужно наследовать именно значение, которое было уже задано...

Comment: Краткая запись - это когда много свойств в одной строчке, но в конечном итоге это просто вопрос терминологии.